# How can I get PHP to instantiate an SDK object with new?

Tags: php, square-connect

I am trying to make an API call in square connect but when I try I get these errors:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/p242rpkr/public_html/SquarePHP/store-config.php on line 59

Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /home/p242rpkr/public_html/SquarePHP/store-config.php on line 60

Here is my code for store-config:

```
require_once '/home/p242rpkr/public_html/SquareSDK/autoload.php';
// API initialization - Configure your online store information
//My real code has the real access token and store name
$GLOBALS['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = "This is my private access token";
$GLOBALS['STORE_NAME'] = "";
$GLOBALS['LOCATION_ID'] = ""; // We'll set this in a moment
$GLOBALS['API_CLIENT_SET'] = false;
// Sanity check that all the needed configuration elements are set
if ($GLOBALS['STORE_NAME'] == null) {
  print(
    "[ERROR] STORE NAME NOT SET. " .
    "Please set a valid store name to use Square Checkout."
  );
  exit;
} else if ($GLOBALS['ACCESS_TOKEN'] == null) {
  print(
    "[ERROR] ACCESS TOKEN NOT SET. Please set a valid authorization token " .
    "(Personal Access Token or OAuth Token) to use Square Checkout."
  );
  exit;
}
/*******************************************************************************
 * @name: initApiClient
 * @param: none - uses the GLOBAL array settings to initialize the client
 * @return: none - adds the ApiClient object to the GLOBAL array
 *
 * @desc:
 * Initializes a Square Connect API client, loads the appropriate
 * location ID and returns an Api object ready for communicating with Square's
 * various API endpoints
 ******************************************************************************/
function initApiClient() {
  // If we've already set the API client, we don't need to do it again
  if ($GLOBALS['API_CLIENT_SET']) { return; }
  // Create and configure a new Configuration object
  $configuration = new \SquareConnect\Configuration();
  \SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($GLOBALS['ACCESS_TOKEN']);
  // Create a LocationsApi client to load the location ID
  $locationsApi = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();
  // Grab the location key for the configured store
  try {
    $apiResponse = $locationsApi->listLocations()->getLocations();
    // There may be more than one location assocaited with the account (e.g,. a
    // brick-and-mortar store and an online store), so we need to run through
    // the response and pull the right location ID
    foreach ($apiResponse['locations'] as $location) {   
     if ($GLOBALS['STORE_NAME'] == $location->getName()) {              
      $GLOBALS['LOCATION_ID'] = $location['id'] ;
          if (!in_array('CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING', $location->getCapabilities())) {
          print(
            "[ERROR] LOCATION  " . $GLOBALS['STORE_NAME'] .
            " can't processs payments"
          );
          exit();
        }


    if ($GLOBALS['LOCATION_ID'] == null) {
      print(
        "[ERROR] LOCATION ID NOT SET. A location ID for " .
        $GLOBALS['STORE_NAME'] . " could not be found"
      );
      exit;
    }
  }
 }
    $GLOBALS['API_CLIENT_SET'] = true;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // Display the exception details, clear out the client since it couldn't
    // be properly initialized, and exit
    echo "The SquareConnect\Configuration object threw an exception while " .
         "calling LocationApi->listLocations: ", $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    $GLOBALS['API_CLIENT'] = null;
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

I believe I have called the autoload function correctly so I do not understand why it is saying that it is a non object when I make the new call.

Comment: Is it possible the API call failed?

Comment: That is something I didn't think of! Is there a way I could find out?

Comment: One way is to add a `print_r($apiResponse);` right after you declare it in the `try` block.

Comment: It doesn't look like it is failing because it printed the object: Array ( [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Location Object ( [id:protected] => myID [name:protected] => myName. [address:protected] => [timezone:protected] => America/Los_Angeles [capabilities:protected] => Array ( [0] => CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING ) ) )

Comment: What I don't see there is `$apiResponse['locations']`

Comment: That what I was just wondering about myself. I tried putting ['name'] in there but it came back empty as well.

Comment: That is because 'name' is not a member of this array.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the for each to just set $location to the first instance of the $apiResponse array (because there is only one) and it worked!

Comment: Glad to help!!!